# What to do so I can import Data.List.Split module in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am new to Haskell, I am thinking to do a small project of processing the spreadsheet data to improve my Haskell. However I don't know how to import the module needed which is the Data.List.Split so that I can split the data.

Not sure if import like this is correct, I am not using cabal but stack.

I added the extra-deps : [split-0.2.3.4] in my .yaml file but still it does not work, it still show could not find Data.List.Split module.

Thank you.

Here is the error I get[image]

Comment: I guess you might need to restart that repl process, so it can detect the added dependency?!

Comment: this is a .yaml file, the correct format is shown in the example above - each package should be on a new line with a - at the start

Comment: Add `split` to the dependencies in the `.cabal` file.

Comment: please replace the picture with text. Thank you.

Comment: @sjakobi I already quit the GHCi and the run stack ghci again in the prompt still it shows "no module found".

Comment: @Michael Litchard , I added the text for the problem.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I am not sure how to do that, I tried adding the Split-0.2.3.4 in the .cabal file but it will be removed automatically when I rerun stack ghci again.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. Simply add "- split == 0.2.3.4" in the package.yaml file "dependencies:" section. Then do the repl again by using "stack ghci" in the command prompt.

Now I am able to use the `splitOn` function from the Data.List.Split module.